# Does reassembly occur at every node?

Tags: ipv6, contiki

This question is in context of IoT protocol stack, IPv6 and Sicslowpan.

In the image below, the adjacent nodes are in radio range of each other as shown for the leftmost node.

[image]

If I send a large packet from node 1 to node 4, then which of the following will happen?

- Reassemble at 2, fragment and forward to 3;

  Reassemble at 3, fragment and forward to 4;

  Reassemble at 4.
- 2 & 3 forward the fragments and reassemble only at 4.

In which particular RFC or trusted document can I read more about this?

Comment: With IPv4 fragmentation happens along the path, but reassembly occurs at the final destination. IPv6 has done away with fragmentation (the IPv6 packet headers do not have the fields to support fragmentation) for performance reasons, with one exception. The IPv6 requirement is that the full path support a minimum MTU of 1280. If a link along the path cannot support this, then fragmentation and reassembly are allowed to happen at both ends of the link, and it must be transparent.

Comment: @RonMaupin: As mentioned in question, I'm speaking in context of IoT where sicslowpan does the fragmentation.

Comment: As I explained, IPv6 requires a 1280 octet MTU, and IPv6 doesn't support fragmentation, so any fragmentation must happen at the link layer, and it must be transparent to IPv6. The IETF has a couple of RFCs for 6LoWPAN, and they explain this. Just search for `rfc 6lowpan`. Unfortunately, resource recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: It is a literal '6', and not 'sics'.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Yes I am reading about rfc 6lowpan but help from community will be useful for me as well as further readers.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I do know. Using 'sicslowpan' to emphasize I'm working on contiki. SICS is for Swedish Institute  of Computer Science.

Comment: There's a relevant discussion here: https://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/28673988/

Comment: @Ron Maupin - IPv6 does support fragmentation. See RFC2460. Routers do not support fragmentation under IPv6 but the protocol understands and supports fragmentation using a mechanism very similar to IPv4

Comment: Are you referring to a host prefragmenting a payload, which is _not_ the same as IPv4 packet fragmentation? I explained the part about link fragmentation, which is not supported by IPv6 itself, but the nodes at the link ends.

Answer (score 1):

**The Short Answer:**

IPV6 does support fragmentation. You can find the details in RFC 2460 Section 5.4 Fragment Header

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt

Under IPV6 if fragmentation is required then the sender must do it (Node 1) and the final receiver will reassemble it (Node 4).

**Longer Answer**

I'm not sure what Sicslowpan uses for transport (UDP, TCP, something else...) but here's what IPV6 will do in general:

The node 1 attempts to send a packet with a "large" size to node 4. The size of this packet is larger than the MTU of one of the segments [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]. Let's say it's too big for segment (2,3).

- Node 1 sends the packet and it makes it safely across (1,2) to node 2.
- Node 2 attempts to send the packet to node 3 and realizes that the MTU for (2,3) cannot support the packet size.
- Node 2 drops the packet and sends and ICMP message to node 1 letting it know what the required MTU is for that route.

At this point Node 1 updates the MTU for traffic it will send to Node 4.

It's the responsibility of the sender to deal with packets dropped due to MTU mismatch along the route.

If Node 1 is using TCP or some other streaming protocol it can change the size of outgoing packets to match the MTU. Any dropped packets would be re-transmitted by the TCP protocol.

If Node 1 is using a UDP or some other datagram based protocol it probably can't reduce the packet size so it will have to fragment the packet when it sends it. The previously sent packets are lost and the application using UDP would need to deal with the loss.

These packets should all make it to Node 4.

Node 4 will reassemble the fragmented packets.

Note that it is possible that another segment along the route, say (3,4) has an even smaller MTU. If this is true then these fragments will also be dropped and another ICMP will be sent with the appropriate MTU and Node 1 will need to update again.